# using member/2 predicate to create a list of events in prolog

Tags: list, prolog

`group_events(G,Events)` is true if `Events` is the list of events that 
should be scheduled for the group `G`. My code is as follows:

```
studying(csen602, group2MET).

event_in_course(csen602, quiz1, quiz).
event_in_course(csen602, quiz2, quiz).
event_in_course(csen602, quiz3, quiz).

group_events(G,[Name|T]):-
    studying(Course,G),
    event_in_course(Course,Name,_),
    \+member(Name,T),
    group_events(G,T).


group_events(G,Events):-
    member(Name,Events),
    studying(Course,G),
    event_in_course(Course,Name,Type).
```

what I get when using the query group_events(group2MET,E) is :

```
E = [quiz1|_G567]
E = [quiz2|_G502]
E = [quiz3|_G502]
E = [_G501, quiz1|_G505]
E = [_G501, quiz2|_G505]
E = [_G501, quiz3|_G505]
```

and so on...

I think the problem is with the `member/2` predicate so any help how to solve this ?

Comment: `_Gxxx` are uninstantiated variables. Trace or step through your program when you query `group_events(group2MET, E).`.

Comment: If you want to _find all_ of something, you should probably use `findall` somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want

```
group_events(G,Events):-
    setof(Event, Course^Desc^(
      studying(Course,G),
      event_in_course(Course,Event,Desc)
    ), Events).
```

Comment: Doesn't `setof/3` fail if _Goal_ has no solutions? (http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=bagof/3)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not 'starting' with an empty list, but with an uninstantiated list, to which you start adding events to be studied and which you are checking for membership.
But that list is still uninstantiated, so the tail of it, and any member you get from it, will be uninstantiated as well.

---

You want to *[find all](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=findall/3)* events that need to be studied, so a good approach would be to first define a `study_event(G, E)` which defines an event `E` that needs to be studied for by a group `G`, and then use `findall/3` to find all such events.